# how to escape quote in ssh command

Tags: linux, ssh

I want to install a the pub key for user `test` using the command below.

I know the root password and the user `test` does not exist.

```
cat test.pub | ssh root@127.0.0.1 "useradd -m test || su - test -c 'umask 077; mkdir /home/test/.ssh; cat >> /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys'"
```

But the command does not work.

```
Error: Creating mailbox file: File exists
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `useradd -m test`. I delete user test by `userdel test && rm -rf /home/test`. It should be `userdel -r test`.

The command below works:

```
cat test.pub | ssh root@127.0.0.1 "useradd -m test && su - test -c 'umask 077; mkdir /home/test/.ssh; cat >> /home/test/.ssh/authorized_keys'"
```